# Как расшифровать "WebSocket Message"?

Tags: websocket, decode

Возможно ли расшифровать данное "WebSocket message"?

2И%JtpE-–ЛC2я%Џ<8E--¶­C2 %і1‘E-‘ЎC2А%ЩеbE-OЇwC2P%ШЃE-іP…C2ў%]m/E-ЖвCB

Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

- Оно, возможно и не "зашифрованное" вовсе.
- Нужно смотреть где в последующем применяется данное сообщение.

  - Если обработка данного сообщения происходит на стороне обозревателя (в ЯваСкрипт), то по способу обработки можно понять какие части сообщения за что отвечают, в противном случае можно оставить это дело.

Comment: Только начинаю изучать веб-сокеты, открыл тренировочный сайт с чатом - он шлёт подобные "зашифрованные" websocket-сообщения (при чем эти сообщения имеют нормальный вид на большинстве других сайтов, именно здесь почему-то набор символов). Так и думаю, может быть есть какой-то декодер специально для таких случаев?